# Cordova requests interceptor - issue with plugins on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, request, intercept

iOS platform.

I made interceptor for the Cordova http requests based on NSURLProtocol. It works fine before you start to use plugins.

When you start to use plugin it start to send "gap://ready" request and plugin doesn't work. If application come to background it stop to send that request and plugin get result when app  come foreground.

I am ignore that request and let system handle that but somehow Cordova cannot handle it. If I remove interceptor Cordova handle that correctly and plugin works.

I am ignore that request by use this filter.

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSString *url = request.URL.absoluteString;

    if([url containsString:@"gap://ready"])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Could I get advice how to handle that request under iOS platform ? Android don't have that request at all.
  Do I need to return specific result ? 
  Do I need to send it to the system ?
  I expected to to handle it by Cordova if I return NO in the filter.